# What type of spell let Snape and Voldemort fly in "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows"?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

In the last book, Snape and Voldemort are seen to be able to fly, after Snape is pushed out of the window in the Hogwarts' classroom. Voldemort flies during his hunt for the owner of the elder wand. How are they able to fly? What is this spell which can enable you to fly, which is stated by the author? (not in Harry Potter Wikia)

I seem to remember there is one such spell known as the Wingardium Leviosa, which lets the person and/or object hit **levitate** in the air, but this wouldn't be counted as actually flying, just as Snape and Voldemort have done. Does J.K. Rowling ever answer this in any of her interviews?

Comment: Isn't that just Apparition?

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Apparition == Teleportation. It's a big deal that Voldy and Snape could actually _fly_ without brooms, something pleb wizards don't attempt because it's helluva hard and dangerous.

Comment: I had the impression that snape and voldemort could fly when I read those parts in deathly hallows. Also, at the front chapters (2nd) of deathly hallows during harry's transportation, voldemort was flying.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'm getting books and movies confused (again). Unaided flight in the books is unique to Voldy and Snape. The HP Wiki says Voldy invented the spell, though there doesn't seem to be a source for that. If true, however, it would mean that Voldy discovered the secret and shared it with only Snape, which means the spell died with them. Who knows how long it'll be before somebody else perfects it?

Comment: what, closed? I am asking whether such a spell existed and if it did what was it called.

Comment: @Isadae so did the other one, and the answer is the same quote.

Answer (score 2):

From J.K. Rowling's [tweet](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/707220859388305408):

> Yes, nearly all wizards use wands, which makes magic easier to
>   channel. Wandless magic is sophisticated and takes more talent.

She also mentioned that More advanced wizards/witches not need a broom to fly.

Brooms are magical tools just like wands, meaning extremely powerful wizards, like Voldemort, can fly without them. This also means every wizard and witch has the ability to fly without a broom, it’s just that most need brooms to channel that power.

Maybe this could have been easily inferred, but it’s nice to hear JKR confirm it.

So, advanced wizards/witches like Dumbledore and Voldemort do not need brooms to fly.

For more details of tweet conversation of JKR please visit this [link](http://elitedaily.com/entertainment/jk-rowling-why-voldemort-fly/1412777/)

Comment: Can you provide the actual evidence in the link that answers the question and not just the first tweet? You seem to have left the tweet with the best evidence out of this answer and put in some random one.

Comment: What @Edlothiad said - there are tweets by her on that link that are more relevant than the one you added.